# Add a new folder to asset path in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I want to create a new folder in `app/assets`, in this folder I have some file, each file have css folder and javascript folder, like the below given addresses:

`app/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`
`app/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js`

I use below code to define `css` file, but not true and rails cannot find and load `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "../plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

How can I declare `css` and `javascript` from `plugin` folder?

Note:
When I want see the `css` file in browser by this address:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I get below error:
`No route matches [GET] "/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

But for css file that exist in `assets/stylesheets/` I can see css file in browser by enter address like top. Why the diffrent beetwin `stylesheets` and `plugins` directory?

Comment: Normally when all the assets that are added to asset paths can only be viewed in browser through the address `http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap.min.css` and not through `http://localhost:3000/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Why you want such a behaviour?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In `application.rb`, add the below lines:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "plugins", "bootstrap","css")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "plugins", "bootstrap","js")
```

Then you will be able to access bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js in your browser,

i.e., `http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap.min.css` / `http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap.min.js`

That means you have added the above to the asset paths.

Now you can call it using `stylesheet_link_tag` or `javascript_include_tag`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I try it and work. I have many directory in `plugins`. For each one I have to add a expression in `application.rb`?!! Do you know a simple way to add all directory in `application.rb`?

Comment: If you want to maintain plugins separately and under different folders, then you need to add it separately. Otherwise, maintain all plugin JS file under `app/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js` and CSS files under `app/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css`. So that would be good to go.

Comment: It worked for me in development mode. It is not working when I deploy to the server. Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466781/rails-rails-root-join-misbehaving-after-deployment