# Rails - Rails.root.join misbehaving after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-assets

I have, in my app/assets directory, the directories javascripts and stylesheets, as any normal Rails app.

I wanted, however, to have a plugins directory as well.

Example:

```
app/assets/plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js
app/assets/plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.css
```

Thing is, if I use

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js' %>
```

I would get a 404 error, as

```
/assets/javascripts/plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js
```

does not exist. I noticed, then, that "plugins" dir was trying to be accessed inside javascripts. I assume this have something to do with "javascript_include_tag".

After some research, I realized I had to include this line into config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets")
```

And it seemed to work. On WEBRick, on development, it worked beautifully.

---

Now I deployed successfully to a server, precompiled the assets, and thought I was ready to go.

the directory

```
/public/assets/
```

was created. Everything in "app/assets/javascripts", "app/assets/stylesheets" and "app/assets/plugins" were precompiled to public/assets

**WHAT WORKED**

```
app/assets/javascripts/login.js
```

was able to be accessed in a view that had

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'login.js' %>
```

**WHAT DIDN'T WORK**

Files that belonged to "plugins".

```
app/assets/plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js
```

was precompiled to

```
public/assets/myPlugin1/somefile.js
```

But when I ran

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js' %>
```

it tries to access

```
/javascripts/plugins/myPlugin1/somefile.js
```

when the correct path, according to my experience in development, would be:

```
/myPlugin1/somefile-(some hex hash).js
```

---

So, as you can see, in production I'm experiencing the same issue as when I haven't added

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets")
```

to application.rb

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go this way:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/plugins/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Or set each plugin, one by one like:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "plugins", "myPlugin")
```

But if you have subdirectories on that myPlugin directory would not load every file. So the first option might be better for you.

Comment: Tried this for `Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/dashboard**/").each do |path|` but couldn't see the folder assets in the console with `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

Comment: are you missing a '/' before those two * or maybe the two * should be after the last slash

Comment: Nope, I've tried `Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/dashboard/**/").each do |path|` as well as `Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/**/*/").each do |path|` and a few other combinations

Comment: That's odd, it worked for me. Try to debug, restart stuff, check spelling or something, I can't help you more than that