# Include custom folder specific assets in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am trying to create separate folders for keeping the assets related to backend and frontend. I planned the following folder structure: `app/assets/dashboard/javascripts` instead of the usual one `app/assets/javascripts`.

[image]

Backend is served via `app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb`, and includes the assets in the following way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard/dashboard', params[:controller], media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'dashboard/dashboard', params[:controller] %>
```

Front end is served via `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, and includes the assets in the following way:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'store/application', params[:controller], media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'store/application', params[:controller] %>
```

I am not sure that what is the correct way to include the assets in this way, and hence getting `404 not found` error for http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/javascripts/dashboard/javascripts/dashboard.js in the console

I've also tried changing the scripts path to `<%= javascript_include_tag 'store/javascripts/application', params[:controller] %>`, but it doesn't work either.
Also tried adding the following piece of code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466781/rails-rails-root-join-misbehaving-after-deployment#answers-header) to application.rb, but it didn't work either:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/**/").each do |path|
      config.assets.paths << path
end
```

With these settings the paths populated in the console are as follows:

```
[9] pry(main)> Rails.application.config.assets.paths 
=> ["/home/vipin8169/projectRoot/inmonarch_website/app/assets/images",
 "/home/vipin8169/projectRoot/xyz/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vipin8169/projectRoot/xyz/app/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vipin8169/projectRoot/xyz/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vipin8169/projectRoot/xyz/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/react-rails-1.6.2/lib/assets/react-source/development-with-addons",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/react-rails-1.6.2/lib/assets/javascripts/",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/javascripts",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/fonts",
 "/home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/images"]
```

Is it supported in rails, altering the assets directory structure in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.rb file. add this

> config.assets.enabled = true
>
> config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "dashboard")

It would add this folder under the assets path. After that

> stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard', params[:controller], media: 'all'

would work.

Comment: Added these two : `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "dashboard")` and `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "store")`, but still getting 404 for http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/stylesheets/dashboard/dashboard.css

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: hmmm.. i am doing it in the same way. It may be some version problem of ruby/rails ?

Comment: using `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]` and `Rails 4.2.6
`